# Run schedule jobs at multi different datetimes get from DB

Tags: spring, cron, schedule

I have a table has *start_at* (datetime) column, I need to run a job each time at these datetime(s), user also could put new record to that table. Datetime of course are different each other, and whatever, for instances:
2019-09-05 11:12:21, 2019-09-05 13:09:42, 2019-09-05 19:34:37,...

I created a cron job that run everyday to get list all start_at values of current date, and cached it in redis, also I put new record has time of current date to this list in redis (if user add new to that table).

Now I have a list contains datetimes need to run a job. How could I do this, please give any ideas or solutions. Thank you!

Input: list differ datetimes get from DB

Expected: schedule jobs run in order at the datetime values get from DB

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that guide which says about schedulers in Spring.
[Task sheduling](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-task-scheduling-with-scheduled-annotation/)

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I known how schedule in Spring, the key problem I met is list schedule times get from DB.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `@Scheduled`'s `fixedRateString` to value from your application.properties (by `@Value(...)` annotation). Then, in runtime, change application.properties `fixedRateString` value to the new value retrieved from database. (or `fixedDelayString`, or whatever you use)

I think there's a nice guide how to do it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties

Comment: Thank you but since there are many differ time values get from DB need execute in order so I think this approach is not suitable.

Comment: Why so, if I could ask? Timestamps you revealed in original post differ by hours, so it is not a performance issue; you can always sort your db records in a particular order to get the next timestamp. If you could explain your thoughts, then it'd be easier to solve this problem :)

Comment: This is a datetime column with many differ anytime values, then I get a list today by time order in redis, and I have to schedule a job with these values each one by one. Thanks